# Excel VBA. Count List entries and set if only one?

Tags: excel, vba

In my speardsheet on the main worksheet cell E18 is configured using data validation as a List with the source set as `sitelist`

sitelist is a named list and contains a list of all site names. This list will shrink or grown depending what the user enters.

Is it possible using VBA to check E18 and see how long that list is, and if there is only one entry then select that using VBA ?

Thanks

UPDATE.
I have tried the following, but they don't appear to be working.

```
Range("MyList").Rows.Count

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyList")
MsgBox tbl.Range.Rows.Count
MsgBox tbl.HeaderRowRange.Rows.Count
MsgBox tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
Set tbl = Nothing
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Since this is not a free code-writing service, edit your question to show  
 what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've been looking into this over the weekend and obviously I'm searching for the wrong thing. I'm trying to work out how many entries are in the list, but the results I find seem to be how many of each list entry exiting in the worksheet.  Could you point me in the right direction ?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld please see my update. Thanks

Comment: How do you manage getting a named range of cells to shrink?

Comment: The admin can add or remove entries from the range, which then changes the size of the list.

Comment: In your code, shouldn't your table name be `sitelist`?  A listobject databody range will expand or shrink automatically as the table is increased/decreased in size. But it won't decrease if you just delete the contents of a cell.  You have to delete that row in the table. You can do this in VBA using worksheet_change event code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry, yes it is `sitelist` I copied that code from another worksheet I was testing on.  Would you expect that code to work ?

Comment: Yes, except for your first line which is not valid VBA syntax. And also provided that, at the time you run the macro, ActiveSheet is the sheet that contains the table.  (Using ActiveSheet and similar, Activate, Select, etc is not good practice in general. Refer to these objects specifically).